# Follow/Highlight signal path after Simulation (Matlab Simulink)

Tags: path, signals, simulation, simulink

I have a model which looks like this :

[image: image1]

In Equipement2 block for example :

[image: image2]

In ETAFON1 block for example :

[image: image3]

In this example i have only put 2 variable "true" (to make equipement2 red) and i would like to know if it's possible to follow/highlight the path of the signals which started from "true" variable or to know why an equipement is red by following the signal in reverse direction at the end of the Simulation like a recap of the signal ?

Comment: I would display the signal values: https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/displaying-block-outputs.html

Comment: @Daniel It could to the job but it's more for User utilization than for debugging. Is it possible to display block outputs by default without selecting port ?